Calculating the area of packaging dieline from DXF file using JavaScript
Here my dxd file dieline image dxd file dieline image
I want to calculate the area of dieline in dxd file
Heres my dxd file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1crCl0uiSOHN4idBfQVTUIu6BJ0ZdhS5-/view?usp=sharing
Here my Next js code:
 

import Head from "next/head";
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import DxfParser from 'dxf-parser';
import { parse as parsePath } from 'svg-path';

export default function Home() {
  const fileInput = useRef(null);
  const [area, setArea] = useState(0);
  const [areaOfObjectInSvg, setAreaOfObjectInSvg] = useState(0);
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({});
  const [svgContent, setSvgContent] = useState('');

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const dxfString = reader.result;
      try {
        const drawing = new DxfParser().parseSync(dxfString);
        const { width, height, calculatedArea } = calculateDimensions(drawing);
        setDimensions({ width, height, drawing });
        setArea(calculatedArea);

        const svgData = renderDXFToSVG(drawing);
        setSvgContent(svgData);

        // Calculate area of SVG content
        const svgArea = calculateAreaOfSVG(svgData);
        setAreaOfObjectInSvg(svgArea);

      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error parsing DXF:', err);
      }
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  };

  const calculateDimensions = (dxf) => {
    let minX = Infinity, minY = Infinity, maxX = -Infinity, maxY = -Infinity;
    let totalArea = 0;
    dxf.entities.forEach(entity => {
      if (entity.type === 'LINE') {
        entity.vertices.forEach(vertex => {
          if (vertex.x < minX) minX = vertex.x;
          if (vertex.y < minY) minY = vertex.y;
          if (vertex.x > maxX) maxX = vertex.x;
          if (vertex.y > maxY) maxY = vertex.y;
        });
      } else if (entity.type === 'LWPOLYLINE') {
        const area = calculatePolygonArea(entity.vertices);
        totalArea += area;
      }
    });

    const width = maxX !== -Infinity && minX !== Infinity ? maxX - minX : 0;
    const height = maxY !== -Infinity && minY !== Infinity ? maxY - minY : 0;

    return { width, height, calculatedArea: totalArea };
  };

  const calculatePolygonArea = (coords) => {
    let area = 0;
    const numPoints = coords.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
      const j = (i + 1) % numPoints;
      area += coords[i].x * coords[j].y;
      area -= coords[j].x * coords[i].y;
    }
    area = Math.abs(area) / 2;
    return area;
  };

  const renderDXFToSVG = (dxf) => {
    const width = dimensions.width;
    const height = dimensions.height;
    let svgElements = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`;

    dxf.entities.forEach(entity => {
        if (entity.type === 'LINE') {
          svgElements += `
            <line 
              x1="${entity.vertices[0].x}" 
              y1="${entity.vertices[0].y}" 
              x2="${entity.vertices[1].x}" 
              y2="${entity.vertices[1].y}" 
              stroke="black" 
              stroke-width="2" />
          `;
        } 
        else if (entity.type === 'ARC') {
          const { center, radius, startAngle, endAngle } = entity;
          const startX = center.x + radius * Math.cos(startAngle);
          const startY = center.y + radius * Math.sin(startAngle);
          const endX = center.x + radius * Math.cos(endAngle);
          const endY = center.y + radius * Math.sin(endAngle);
  
          const largeArcFlag = (Math.abs(endAngle - startAngle) > Math.PI) ? 1 : 0;
          const sweepFlag = 1;
  
          const pathData = `
            M ${startX} ${startY}
            A ${radius} ${radius} 0 ${largeArcFlag} ${sweepFlag} ${endX} ${endY}
          `;
  
          svgElements += `
            <path 
              d="${pathData}" 
              stroke="black" 
              stroke-width="2" 
              fill="none" />
          `;
        } else if (entity.type === 'LWPOLYLINE') {
          const points = entity.vertices.map(v => `${v.x},${v.y}`).join(' ');
          svgElements += `
            <polygon 
              points="${points}" 
              stroke="black" 
              stroke-width="2" 
              fill="none" />
          `;
        }
    });

    svgElements += `</svg>`;
    return svgElements;
  };

  const calculateAreaOfSVG = (svgContent) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const svgDoc = parser.parseFromString(svgContent, 'image/svg+xml');
    const svg = svgDoc.documentElement;

    let totalArea = 0;

    svg.querySelectorAll('path').forEach(shape => {
      const pathData = shape.getAttribute('d');
      const parsedPath = parsePath(pathData);
      const pathArea = calculatePathArea(parsedPath);
      totalArea += pathArea;
    });

    svg.querySelectorAll('polygon').forEach(shape => {
      const points = shape.getAttribute('points').trim().split(/\s+/);
      const coords = points.map(point => point.split(',').map(Number));
      const polygonArea = calculatePolygonArea(coords);
      totalArea += polygonArea;
    });

    return totalArea;
  };

  const calculatePathArea = (path) => {
    const points = [];
    path.forEach(segment => {
      if (segment.command === 'M') {
        points.push([segment.x, segment.y]);
      } else if (segment.command === 'L') {
        points.push([segment.x, segment.y]);
      } else if (segment.command === 'Z') {
        points.push(points[0]);
      }
    });
    return calculatePolygonArea(points);
  };


  function extractPoints(segments) {
    let points = [];

    segments.forEach(segment => {
      if (segment.type === 'LINE') {
        points.push(segment.vertices[0]);
        points.push(segment.vertices[1]);
      } else if (segment.type === 'ARC') {
      }
    });

    return points;
  }

  function isShapeClosed(vertices) {
    const tolerance = 0.0001; // Tolerance for floating-point comparison

    // Extract points from the shape segments
    const points = extractPoints(vertices);

    // Check if the first and last points are approximately equal
    if (points.length < 2) {
      return false;
    }

    const firstPoint = points[0];
    const lastPoint = points[points.length - 1];

    return Math.abs(firstPoint.x - lastPoint.x) < tolerance &&
      Math.abs(firstPoint.y - lastPoint.y) < tolerance;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>DXF PARSER</title>
        <meta name="description" content="DXF PARSER BY HAMMAD" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <input type="file" ref={fileInput} onChange={handleFileChange} />

        <div className="flex gap-[30px] mt-[30px]">
          <div>
            <p>Width: {dimensions?.width?.toFixed(3)} mm</p>
            <p>Height: {dimensions?.height?.toFixed(3)} mm</p>
          </div>

          <div>
            <p>Width: {(dimensions?.width * 0.0393701).toFixed(3)} inches</p>
            <p>Height: {(dimensions?.height * 0.0393701).toFixed(3)} inches</p>
          </div>

          <h2>Total Area: {((dimensions?.width *  dimensions?.height) / 100).toFixed(3)} cm2</h2>
          <div>Area of SVG Object: {areaOfObjectInSvg.toFixed(3)} cm2</div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div className="main_svg_class" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svgContent }} />
      </main>
    </>
  );
}


Need Corrected Code to Calculate the accurate dieline area through the dxf file
